# Исключение фраз из регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Каким образом простым способом исключить из регулярного выражения несколько фраз?

Регулярное выражение: `/подарю/`. Нужно исключить из него "не подарю".

Чтобы не срабатывало на такое предложение:

> Пишите мне в личку я **не подарю** подарок

Comment: `(?<!не )подарю`  https://regex101.com/r/EAM5KD/1  документация https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4

Comment: @Mike, большое спасибо! Оформите как ответ, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используем проверку с [просмотром назад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4).

```
(?<!не )подарю
```

Пример на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EAM5KD/1)